# JavaScript - Implementing the latest Google Sign In

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-signin

I'm looking at the google docs:

https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference?hl=de

but they are useless as always what google provides, this is what I tried so far:

```
var startApp = function() {
    window.onload = function () {
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id: googleSignInClientId,
          callback: handleCredentialResponse
        });
        google.accounts.id.prompt();
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(document.getElementById("button_google_login"), {
            theme: 'outline',
            size: 'large',
            click_listener: onClickHandler
          });
      };
};

function onClickHandler(){
    console.log("Sign in with Google button clicked...")
  }

var initGoogleDone = false;
function initGoogle(){
    if(!initGoogleDone){
        initGoogleDone = true;
        startApp(); 
    }
}

function open_signin() {
    initGoogle();
    $('#lightbox').fadeIn('fast');
}
```

When I click on `button_google_login`, nothing happens, and I don't know how exactly to use the callback: `handleCredentialResponse` since there are no examples

Comment: Welcome to stack please read [ask] edit your question describe what it is you are trying to do then describe what you have tried and define the issues.     As it is currently  written the only thing i understand is your dislike for googles docs.   You have not stated what is not working and what your even trying to do.   These are two completely different systems they are nothing alike assuming that it will work like the old one is an incorrect assumption to begin with.

Comment: The only think I'm using from the old code is: var initGoogleDone = false;
function initGoogle(){
    if(!initGoogleDone){
        initGoogleDone = true;
        startApp(); 
    }
}

function open_signin() {
    initGoogle();
    $('#lightbox').fadeIn('fast');
} and I think there is nothing wrong with that.

Comment: And what I'm trying to archive is written in the title!

Comment: And I don't get any errors, nor does it starts the sign in process and I don't know how exactly to use: handleCredentialResponse since there are no examples for that!

Comment: Where exactly did you get the code you are using?

Comment: window.onload = function () {
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
          client_id: googleSignInClientId,
          callback: handleCredentialResponse
        });
        google.accounts.id.prompt();
      }; is from the doc I liked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tested this and requests authorization and outputs the Id token jwt in the console.

Just make sure if you are testing with localhost that you have added

```
http://localhost
```

In JavaScript origin without the port.

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer></script>
<script>
    function handleCredentialResponse(response) {
        console.log("Encoded JWT ID token: " + response.credential);
        var tokens = response.credential.split(".");
        var payload = JSON.parse(atob(tokens[1]));  
        console.log(`user id ${payload.sub}`)
        console.log(`user name ${payload.name}`)
        console.log(`user picture ${payload.picture}`)
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        google.accounts.id.initialize({
            client_id: "[REDACTED]",
            callback: handleCredentialResponse
        });
        google.accounts.id.renderButton(
            document.getElementById("buttonDiv"),
            { theme: "outline", size: "large" }  // customization attributes
        );
        google.accounts.id.prompt(); // also display the One Tap dialog
    }
</script>
<div id="buttonDiv"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

## what is a JWT

The response.credential field is the ID token as a base64 encoded JSON Web Token (JWT) string.

A JWT or Json web token is the response from the signin process

If you take this value and place it in https://jwt.io/ you can see the claims that are being returned by the authorization server.

This claim set defines the user who has signed in to your application and gives you some interesting information about them.

```
{
  "iss": "https://accounts.google.com",
  "nbf": 1674833031,
  "aud": "[Audience your client id]",
  "sub": "117200475532672775346",
  "email": "[REDACTED]",
  "email_verified": true,
  "azp": "[REDACTED]",
  "name": "Linda Lawton",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AEdFTp46WTOIbHj5Nl1VJRFf4Izj9YrX61i75F16H1qSA1Q=s96-c",
  "given_name": "Linda",
  "family_name": "Lawton",
  "iat": 1674833331,
  "exp": 1674836931,
  "jti": "3aaf07a28c84796145ce49c490e14dffe3328779"
}
```

This is standard with all authencation servers.

The JWT is in three parts, header, payload and signature. they are joined by a .

My code splits the jwt by the .

```
var tokens = response.credential.split(".");
```

Then parses the payload

```
var payload = JSON.parse(atob(tokens[1]));
```

Resulting in

```
 console.log(`user id ${payload.sub}`)
 console.log(`user name ${payload.name}`)
 console.log(`user picture ${payload.picture}`)
```

Comment: I have the super power to help get the docs fixed.  I'm happy to forward constructive criticism on to the team minus the monkey part.  I cant send that to to google. 

Comment: Yeah better leave that out :D Alright this works now, thanks!

Comment: I sent a better worded request for adding the library :)   Pro tip.   This is signin not Oauth2 its not going to work the same as the old system, Im not sure what you are doing exactly.

Comment: I should Put out a YouTube Video on this.

Comment: Yeah I just inspected the whole response and I don't get what I used to get: the user ID with which I can identify him, the profile image and the nickname. What is the purpose of the new stuff? Why is google keep changing stuff that just works?? Will they be fired if they don't come up with new useless stuff every month which makes life more complicated than it needs to be?

Comment: The jwt contains the User id.   Just put it in JWT.io you can see the claims there.

Comment: What is jwt and what do you mean by "Just put it in JWT.io"? It's like people from google think that they explain stuff to coworkers which should know what all this stuff suppose to mean. Will I also get the profile image url and nickname as I used to? Jesus how many hours I already wasted for something that gives zero improvements compared to the old way

Comment: if you take the response from   response.credential and place it in https://jwt.io/ you will see the full claim set in the response.    I have edited it to show you how to grab the user id.   The sub claim is the users internal google user id.     Sec and I will find you the name and image

Comment: There you go Name, user id, and picture.

Comment: Alright but how can I convert the response.credential string to the data automatically? Do I have to use an jwt.io api if there is any? Or do I have to do this server side? Is it possible with PHP? Jesus why.. JUST WHY???

Comment: Check my updated code I have converted it for you and answered your other question.

Comment: NP its a hobby.  